# Displaying parametres from a variable decision for each time the dvar == 1

Tags: excel, cplex, opl

I just get started on CPLEX so this is my problem:

I do have an issue I have a variable decision  Y (patient allocated =1 if yes for the day i the hour h  ) with three parameters (patient daytime ) and I want to display on a table on excel those results. one table with the `Y==1` and their parameters beside this table.

if  `Ypih == Zpm= 1`  (Zpm variable decision if the patient p is consulted from the doctor m )     then write on excel the patient p is registered to consult the doctor m on the day I at the hour h.

my problem is that i cannot display the parameters for their ranges for every instance of the loop .

so how to cross the pool solution to get the values of pih when `Y==1==Z` and display them

Comment: Insert code snippets instead of writing the code within the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve your problem as pointed below (assuming you're using the ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio C++ library).

```
// solve your model
cplex.solve();

// now, we will verify all variables that are equal to 1
// first, we will loop through variables Y
for (int p_ = 0; p_ < maxP; p_++) {
  for (int i_ = 0; i_ < maxI; i_++) {
    for (int h_ = 0; h_ < maxH; h_++) {
      // if Y_{pih} == 1
      if (cplex.getValue(cplex.varY[p_][i_][h_]) == 1) {
        // we will look if there is a variable Z == 1
        for (int m_ = 0; m_ < maxM; m_++) {
          if (cplex.getValue(cplex.varZ[p_][m_] == 1) {
            // print or store your variables
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After solving your model, you will need to verify which variables are equal to one. Thus, you can loop through all of your model variables and verify whether they are one or not, using the `getValue` CPLEX function.

See [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html#getValues) for a description regarding the CPLEX function.